# How build a custom css button with strip

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can i build this example button, with strip red (when focus) and blue.

[button example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhFiv.png)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.button:hover {
    border-left: 3px solid blue;
}
```